# Safari 7.0 (Mavericks) lost connection when trying the following URL

Tags: ios, safari, nsurlconnection, osx-mavericks, playready

When I try to access [this](https://services.wmdrm.windowsmedia.com/SecureClock/?petition) on Safari 7.0 (or on IOS 7) I am getting a **connection lost**.

But on Safari 6.0.5 (or IOS 6.0.1) the link works fine.

Does anybody encounter a similar issue or know the cause of it?

Thanks alot.

I saw that the error is **-1005** which is:

```
"NSURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost = kCFURLErrorNetworkConnectionLost"
```